# Programmatically highlight marker on Kendo bar chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I think what I am asking is impossible, or at least so complex/hacky it would not be worth it-but in case I am wrong...please let me know.

I have a series of 4 kendo dataviz bar charts, each representing the same set of objects, each chart graphically displaying one property of the objects. What I would like is if a marker on one chart is clicked (so that object is "selected"), to highlight this object's marker on the other 3 charts. See pic for example:

[image]

I have looked through the Kendo Dataviz website/docs, inspected the SVG markup, and looked through the object returned on the series click (in Visual Studio), but haven't found anything that could be used to accomplish this. The one thing I have come up with is redrawing all the charts with the selected item "marked" within the data array so when it is redrawn, that item can be redrawn with a different color...but I'd like to avoid redrawing all the charts each time, if possible.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I would greatly appreciate ideas, the least complex the better. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The closest way I know of achieving this without a redraw would be to use the [axis selection](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/selection) property as a selection slider with a restricted width to one column range and prevent resizing. This would simulate a selection highlight without redrawing.

Comment: Interesting! Good suggestion. I'll try it and mark as answer if it works, but it does sound promising...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use plotBands property on the CategoryAxis. This is how I am doing it:
$("#chart").data("kendoChart").setOptions({ categoryAxis: { plotBands: [{ from: index, to: index + 1, color: "#ffd0c0", opacity: 0.4 }] } });